# If and else to share dialog function to use from another component

Tags: angular, if-statement

Currently I have 2 working components assuming the name is component A and B. Component B has a dialog attach to it from a button and Component A has no dialog attach to their button but that button has a `routerlink` that goes to component B page. I'm not sure if it will work. How do I write a if and else statement to trigger the modal from component B function to use on component A.

Do I still need get route from component B?

Appreciate some help with thanks.

Component A

```
<div class="work-col">
        <div class="work-content-style">{{ homeItem.home_title }}</div>
        <div class="work-content-style-2">{{ homeItem.home_description }}</div>
        <a routerLink="/work" class="work-btn-style" (click)="isModal">{{homeItem.home_button_text}}</a>
</div>
```

Component A ts

```
export class HomeWorkComponent implements OnInit {
homeWork = '';
routeName: string;
isModal = false;
public isScrolled: boolean;

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any, private route:ActivatedRoute) {
}
shareDialog() {
  console.log(this.isModal);
  const modal = this.isModal;
  const workRoute = this.routeName;
  if click this button goes to work route {
  triggers the modal
  } else {
  do nothing? or suggestion 
  }

ngOnInit() {
 this.routeName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap['work'];
}

initMap(data: any) {
  const home = data;
  this.homeWork = home;
  console.log(this.homeWork);
}
```

}

Component B

```
export class WorkDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
array = [];
dialogResult: String = '';

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) { }
   }

   openDialog(id: number) {
     const workObj = this.array[id];
     const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(WorkModalComponent, {
       width: '1200px',
       height: '100%',
       data: workObj
     });

     dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog closed: ${result}`);
      this.dialogResult = result;
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please attach some minimal code of your components describing the functionality and what does not work?

Comment: Where does this button need to be showed on component A or B or both?

Comment: I just need component A to have the same dialog popup button as B has.